# Is Aws GetObject downloading all the data into memory or to a file cache?

Tags: c++, amazon-s3

Here is a method to access a file from S3:

`GetObject(...)` returns `Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectOutcome`
`Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectOutcome` has `GetResultWithOwnership().GetBody()` method to return `Aws::IOStream`

I wonder if that `Aws::IOStream` is a string stream to memory where whole file was downloaded to, or a stream to a file if the file was cached, or maybe it indeed reads the file block by block from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it downloads all the body into memory and uses `stringbuf`.
There is a method how to download avoid loading all the file to memory:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/configuring-iostreams.html

Example from that page in case the link is removed:

```
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest;
getObjectRequest.SetBucket(fullBucketName);
getObjectRequest.SetKey(keyName);
getObjectRequest.SetResponseStreamFactory([](){
    return Aws::New<Aws::FStream>(
        ALLOCATION_TAG, DOWNLOADED_FILENAME, std::ios_base::out); });

auto getObjectOutcome = s3Client->GetObject(getObjectRequest);
```